# Css inverted Borders 2.0

Tags: css, border, transparency

people have come up with inverted borders (here's an example) : https://css-tricks.com/examples/RoundOutTabs/

but it's always a hack. here's my issue :

[image]

I'm going to be overlaying the box with inverted corners over a background that is has dynamic transparency and has pictures underneath.

I can't pull this trick off in this scenario.

Isn't it possible to "cut out" extra portions of the tab? to achieve the same effect but in a more universally applicable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider linear/radial-gradient to create the whole element without all these pseudo-element:

```css
.active {
  padding:20px 0;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  background:
  radial-gradient(circle at bottom right,orange 50%,transparent 53%) 4px 0/16px 10px no-repeat,
  radial-gradient(circle at bottom left,orange 50%,transparent 53%) calc(100% - 4px) 0%/16px 10px no-repeat,
  radial-gradient(circle at top left,transparent 50%,orange 55%) 0% 100%/16px 10px no-repeat,
  radial-gradient(circle at top right,transparent 50%,orange 55%) 100% 100%/16px 10px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(orange,orange) 20px 0px/calc(100% - 40px) 20px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(orange,orange) 10px 10px/calc(100% - 20px) 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<span class="active">
 link
</span>
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the same code without the use of the shorthand version:

```css
.active {
  padding:20px 0;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  background-image:
  radial-gradient(circle at bottom right,orange 50%,transparent 53%),
  radial-gradient(circle at bottom left,orange 50%,transparent 53%),
  radial-gradient(circle at top left,transparent 50%,orange 55%),
  radial-gradient(circle at top right,transparent 50%,orange 55%),
  linear-gradient(orange,orange),
  linear-gradient(orange,orange);
  background-position:4px 0,calc(100% - 4px) 0%,0% 100%,100% 100%,20px 0,10px 10px;
  background-size:16px 10px,16px 10px,16px 10px,16px 10px,calc(100% - 40px) 20px,calc(100% - 20px) 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<span class="active">
 link
</span>
```

Comment: the syntax seems to be broken there. it won't compile under Angular 5

Comment: @tatsu it's not broken ;) but with angular you cannot use the shorthand without issue ... i face this before, you need to split the properties, am gonna edit my answer

Comment: @tatsu i updated, you may try with the second version of the code

Comment: `^\r\n      Incompatible units: 'px' and '%'.\r\n ` I think it's the first part it doesn't like. I've played around with it a bit but it never seems satisfied. I always get a different error about the unit of measurement being unsatisfactory or unresolvable, any ideas?

Comment: @tatsu there is `4px 0%` remove the % it's useless

Comment: same... :  `^\r\n      Incompatible units: 'px' and '%'.\r\n`

Comment: @tatsu or maybe it's the calc that use both % and px .. in this case simply replace the 100% with the width of the element in this case 100px

Comment: maybe if I put calc everywhere?

Comment: @tatsu it will become complicated ... in this case if you have `100% - 20px` simply put it 80px so do the caclulation your self ... you only have 3 calc, so let's try without them to see if it solves the issue

Comment: `background:
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom right,orange 50%,transparent 53%) 4px 0/16px 10px no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom left,orange 50%,transparent 53%) calc(100px - 4px) 0/16px 10px no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(circle at top left,transparent 50%,orange 55%) 0 100px/16px 10px no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(circle at top right,transparent 50%,orange 55%) 100px 100px/16px 10px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(orange,orange) 20px calc(0 / calc(100px - 40px)) 20px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(orange,orange) 10px calc(10px / calc(100px - 20px)) 100px no-repeat;`

Comment: the above worked. well... compiles. the browser won't interpret it.

Comment: @tatsu yes, as i said he didn't like the mix of % and px inside the calc ... so you can simplify in this case by doing the calc your self if you know the width

Comment: @tatsu by the way i see you also change the % of background postion to px .. ma pretty use these will work as they need to be %

Comment: still can't figure it out. move to disscussion?

Comment: what do the `0/16px` mean? I don't understand why just replacing them with `0` gives `missmatched property value`.

Comment: `/` separate between the position and the size ... it's like this `x y/width height` ... that's why i provided the other solution to separate properties and avoid this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166305/discussion-between-temani-afif-and-tatsu).

Comment: hey I'm coming back to this wondering : did you use a tool to generate this Css or did you do it all by hand? because I'd very much like to use your tool because customizing it for, say, a vertical tab instead of a horizontal tab is proving to be arduous. (yes I'm fine with having to remove the shorthand myself each time by hand)

Comment: @tatsu no it's all handy :) my only tool is my brain ;)

Comment: that's nuts. I can't work it out. do you not even use pen and paper?  could you please edit your answer to add an explanation (of the non-shorthand) what is happening?

Comment: @tatsu `that's nuts`--> it's the experience and i don't use pen and paper ... by the way if you want to understand it's not difficlut .. take them one by one, change color to identify them and play with values then you will understand what is happen .. the magic is when they all are with the same color to create the illusion of a perfect shape, but once you make them different color, the magic will break ;) and then you will see what is happening

Comment: trial and error : https://jsfiddle.net/qzu9fmrq/30/ I gotta say It's really hard. If I feel up to the task I'll try drafting up a roadmap to reading this.

Comment: I'm unsatisfied with the way the top and bottom part don't end in a single pixel (or less) but rather are thick of about 3-4 pixels. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @tatsu i know it's a bit complicate and not easy at all ... nothing is wrong but you have to adjust positon/ and size, you are almost good ... just need to shift them a bit to the right (decrease size)